# Accounts clean up using Cloudingo

Tags: account, duplicate-management, cleanup, cloudingo

I have a task in hand to clean up  the accounts, basically, remove all the duplicates accounts, The tool my client asked to use is Cloudingo, I am very new to SF administration and Cloudingo, can anyone please help me with the step by step process of removing the duplicates by creating the filters, what approach/logic should be in place for removing the duplicate accounts.

Also once identified the duplicates what should be the approach for merging those accounts.

Please note I have Cloudingo dashboard up and running in Full sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

The first place that you should check (should have) would be the [Cloudingo Documentation](https://help.cloudingo.com/documentation-library/)
Once you have done so, you might specifically check the [Getting Started Guide](https://help.cloudingo.com/uploads/Cloudingo-Quick-Start-Guide.pdf)

and from there >

> **Creating Fitlers:**
>
> Step 1 | Define the Filter A filter is defined by the objects it scans
>   for duplicates. Single-table filters compare like object to like
>   object (example: contacts to contacts). Multi-table filters compare
>   leads to either accounts or contacts.
>
> Step 2 | Choose Which Fields to
>   Match Select standard or custom fields to identify duplicate matches.
>   The primary field is one that everything is grouped by to begin with.
>   Secondary fields are used to further filter or match duplicates.
>
> Step 3 | Fine Tune Your Results By default Cloudingo will scan your entire
>   database for duplicates. However, you can choose to limit the search
>   by setting parameters, such as by date or record type.